# What’s the problem with this fluent builder?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've implement a GroupingBuilder that delegates to the groupingBy factory method , What’s the problem with this fluent builder? And how i can make in effective DSL forms?

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
public class GroupingBuilder<T, D, K> {
    private final Collector<? super T, ?, Map<K, D>> collector;
    private GroupingBuilder(Collector<? super T, ?, Map<K, D>> collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }
    public Collector<? super T, ?, Map<K, D>> get() {
        return collector;
    }
    public <J> GroupingBuilder<T, Map<K, D>, J>
    after(Function<? super T, ? extends J> classifier) {
        return new GroupingBuilder<>(groupingBy(classifier, collector));
    }
    public static <T, D, K> GroupingBuilder<T, List<T>, K>
    groupOn(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier) {
        return new GroupingBuilder<>(groupingBy(classifier));
    }
}
```

Comment: "*What’s the problem with this fluent builder?*" - You tell us! What is the problem? Do you get a compiler error? If so: please [edit] the post and add the compiler error. Do you get an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code throwing the exception. Do you observe undesired behaviour? If so: please [edit] the question and add expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: I guess its not throwing exception its on Domain-specific languages with lambdas function concepts, Its popular question on  Dsl and Lambda usages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write in more readable format with sequence of functions defined with lambda expressions  more over as you can see in below ,

```html
        Collector<? super Car, ?, Map<Brand, Map<Color, List<Car>>>>
        carGroupingCollector =
        groupOn(Car::getColor).after(Car::getBrand).get()
```

The use of this is counterintuitive because the grouping functions have to be written in reverse order relative to the corresponding nested grouping level. If you try to refactor this fluent builder to fix the ordering issue, you realize that unfortunately, the Java type system won’t allow you to do this.